# Inexplicable error 193 with LoadLibrary of a C++ DLL using \clr

Tags: c++, boost, clr, loadlibrary

We have an user interface developped in C++ using Boost 1.54.0 and QT 4.8.6.
This interface can call computation module. Each module must implement a (non pure) abstract class and be linked to a given .lib generated during interface compilation. After launching the interface, we indicate the path of the module dll which is loaded using QLibrary.

Everything worked perfectly with native C++ module but recently we started developping new modules using .NET 3.5 (C#). We want the interface can call this module so we decided to create an intermediate c++ project using \clr : this project implements the abstract class and can call managed .NET code thanks to \clr mode.

Now we have a big problem : we cannot achieve to load correctly the intermediate C++ problem. We tried with the kernel32 method LoadLibrary and we obtained an error code 193 (ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT). It is very surprising because all the projects are compiled for Win32/x86 and the computer is using a Windows Vista 32 bits.

Everything seems normal with dependancy walker :
[image]

We used dumpbin but everything seemed normal :

> Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 9.00.30729.01 Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Dump of file Lien.dll
>
> PE signature found
>
> File Type: DLL
>
> FILE HEADER VALUES
>                14C machine (x86)
>
> ```
>            6 number of sections
>     53CF72B5 time date stamp Wed Jul 23 10:30:45 2014
>            0 file pointer to symbol table
>            0 number of symbols
>           E0 size of optional header
>         2102 characteristics
>                Executable
>                32 bit word machine
>                DLL
> ```

Comment: First, a computer that is running 32-bit Windows is capable of building 64-bit modules.  So it doesn't matter what the bitness of the OS is.  Second, write a simple `main` program that does nothing except call "LoadLibrary" on the module that you're having trouble with.  If you can't get that to work, then work on that simple program until you can get it to work.

Comment: Use BOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK
=> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353128/loadlibrary-193

Comment: The error code doesn't necessarily refer to *your* DLL, it can also apply to any dependent DLLs that need to be loaded.  That gets pretty tricky if you use LoadLibrary() to load a mixed-mode .NET assembly, you are blind as a bat to any mishaps in the managed code.  Like not having the required .NET Framework version installed, also reported as error 193.  With non-zero odds that it is a later version than 3.5 btw if you use the wrong toolchain, have a look-see with ildasm.exe

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the link Patrice Pezillier.
The issue was resolved by using your link : boost was the culprit.